# Angular ng-animate using javascript not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

I tried to implement the demo example using JS but something went wrong with ng-switch ... I can see that new elements are being added in the dom, but ng-switch is not removing the unwanted DIVs. can you pls help ...

Here is the **[Fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/LFFav/9/)**

```
var ngModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
ngModule.animation('js-wave-enter', function () {
return {
    setup: function (element) {
        //prepare the element for animation
        element.css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'left': '100%' });
    },
    start: function (element, done, memo) {
        //start the animation
        element.animate({ 'left': 0  }, function () {
            //call when the animation is complete
            done();
        });
    }
}
});

ngModule.animation('js-wave-leave', function () {
return {
    setup: function (element) {
        //prepare the element for animation
        element.css({'position': 'absolute',  'left': 0     });           
    },
    start: function (element, done, memo) {
        //start the animation
        element.animate({ 'left': '-100%'      }, function () {
            //call when the animation is complete
            done();
        });
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQLite does not include the animate() method. You need to include jQuery proper before you include Angular and your code will work fine. So just add the following before the script tag that includes AngularJS:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/LFFav/10/)

Comment: thanks a ton.. there is another issue if u could help.. it seems that `element.css('height') ` doesnt work if I remove the jquery... line 11,12  [fiddle.. ] (http://jsfiddle.net/LFFav/14/) .. any idea why..?

Comment: If you inspect the DOM you'll see 2 things: 1) The height for your 1st ng-switch DIV is 0, but for the 2nd it's 20px. And 2) when the the CSS animation runs for a brief moment both the `true` and `false` DIVs are shown. In the JS animator that never happens. So I believe the error lies somewhere in one (or both) of those inconsistencies.

Comment: There is a nice in depth article here covering all the new animation hooks in 1.1.4 here: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html